# List only K2 items that have a video

Tags: k2, content-filtering

I need to show a list of only the items from K2 articles that have the media (video) field filled.
The K2 module permit this but has no pagination and I need it.
Any idea or extensions to suggest?
I would like to avoid hacking the code since I would like to keep it ready to receive official updates, but a clean override can be considered if it is the only solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: Adding pagination to the K2 content module could be also a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding pagination to the module as Manny suggest is a good way to solve it.

You can duplicate the mod_k2_content to mod_k2_contentPagination
and do the following modifications :
http://www.joomreem.com/joomla-developer-s-tips-and-tricks/item/56-k2-content-module-with-pagination-jquery-flavor.html

Comment: Merci beaucoup Pierre! I thought to this solution but my concern was to paginate server side in order to avoid to overload the page load since the items to retrieve could be a lot, but in any case I will consider this solution if there are no others. :)

Comment: Glad this help you